# Oracle query for nested JSON (with duplicate field names and dynamic multiple nested levels)

Tags: sql, json, oracle, nested, oracle12c

I have sample JSON as below, please note how many times "listOfItems" tag appears is dynamic, it can be just one or many children's within child's and so on. 
JSON's are stored in a CLOB column, this is just one sample JSON to help understand its structure. The nested levels is dynamic and vary from one JSON to another. 
The table will have many rows with varying nested levels. I should be able to search for a field and its value across all rows to figure out the matching rows or the rows that have the element and its value per input.

```
{
"id": 1000,
"version": 1,  
"number": "123456",
"type": "Y",
"itemName": "some name1",
"listOfItems": [
{
  "id": 2000,
  "version": 2,

  "number": "234567",
  "type": "Y",
  "itemName": "some name2",

  "listOfItems": [
    {
      "id": 3000,
      "version": 3,

      "number": "345678",
      "type": "Y",
      "itemName": "some name3",

      "listOfItems": [
        {
          "id": 4000,
          "version": 4,

          "number": "456789",
          "type": "N",
          "itemName": "some name2",

          "listOfItems": [
            {
              "id": 5000,
              "version": 5,

              "number": "567890",
              "type": "N",
              "itemName": "some name3",

              "listOfItems": [                    
              ]                  
            },
            {
              "id": 6000,
              "version": 6,

              "number": "678901",
              "type": "N",
              "itemName": "some name3",

              "listOfItems": [

              ]

            }                
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

Oracle version is - Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2.0)
The requirement is to create a view from all nested levels with all available child fields and their values. So later we can query this view to find if an item with a field value or name, etc exists within a given JSON or not.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent homework project.  What have you tried so far? Please click on edit and add in your code. And tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: My best bet was to use JSON_TABLE with NESTED PATH and create a view with all the fields and their values so later we can query this view. But that approach is not helping here because of 2 reasons: 1) The nested levels will vary across rows 2) The field names are repeated at all levels. If we have a fixed nested level structure JSON and if field names are not duplicated across levels, that approach is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NESTED PATH` with a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

**Oracle 12 Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  value CLOB
  CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK( value IS JSON )
);

INSERT INTO t VALUES ( '{"id":1000,"version":1,"number":"123456","type":"Y","itemName":"some name1","listOfItems":[{"id":2000,"version":2,"number":"234567","type":"Y","itemName":"some name2","listOfItems":[{"id":3000,"version":3,"number":"345678","type":"Y","itemName":"some name3","listOfItems":[{"id":4000,"version":4,"number":"456789","type":"N","itemName":"some name2","listOfItems":[{"id":5000,"version":5,"number":"567890","type":"N","itemName":"some name3","listOfItems":[]},{"id":6000,"version":6,"number":"678901","type":"N","itemName":"some name3","listOfItems":[]}]}]}]}]}' );
```

**Query**:

```
WITH data ( parent, id, version, "number", "type", itemName, child ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         NULL,
         j.id,
         j.version,
         j."number",
         j."type",
         j.itemName,
         j.child
  FROM   t,
         JSON_TABLE(
           t.value,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             id       NUMBER       PATH '$.id',
             version  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.version',
             "number" VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.number',
             "type"   VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.type',
             itemName VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.itemName',
             child    VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.listOfItems'
           )
         ) j
UNION ALL
  SELECT d.id,
         k.id,
         k.version,
         k."number",
         k."type",
         k.itemName,
         k.child
  FROM   data d,
         JSON_TABLE(
           d.child,
           '$'
           COLUMNS (
             NESTED PATH '$[*]'
               COLUMNS (
                 id       NUMBER       PATH '$.id',
                 version  VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.version',
                 "number" VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.number',
                 "type"   VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.type',
                 itemName VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.itemName',
                 child    VARCHAR2(4000) FORMAT JSON PATH '$.listOfItems'
               )
           )
         ) k
  WHERE d.child IS NOT NULL
  AND   d.child <> '[]'
)
SELECT parent,
       id,
       version,
       "number",
       "type",
       itemName
FROM   data;
```

**Result**:

```
PARENT   ID VERSION number type ITEMNAME
------ ---- ------- ------ ---- ----------
(NULL) 1000       1 123456    Y some name1
  1000 2000       2 234567    Y some name2
  2000 3000       3 345678    Y some name3
  3000 4000       4 456789    N some name2
  4000 5000       5 567890    N some name3
  4000 6000       6 678901    N some name3
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this is really good when the length of the whole JSON is small. I have given stripped version of the full JSON, the actual JSON is more than 10K in size, so the child    VARCHAR2(4000) is not helping and i cannot go more than 4k i guess.

Comment: @common The Oracle 12 JSON functions only seem to support `VARCHAR2` return values and not `CLOB`s so you do seem to be limited to 4000 characters. They also do not allow dynamic paths (which was going to be my other solution) and only support text literals for the path. The only other solution I can think of is to use a Java JSON parser and use `CREATE JAVA` to put it into the database.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs. Tried to convert JSON to XML and run queries on XML, the performance is very slow, considering these JSON/XML documents are large and with dynamic nested paths. Going to store the required key element values (don't need all elements) in a separate table for the search.